# Why does my code not work? (Repeating loop with return)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have no idea why this code does not work. The whole idea about it is to make the value bigger until it's bigger than score.

```
if(score > height && rocketlaunch == false)
{
    @try
    {
         height = [self makebigger:height];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
         height = height + 4000;
    }
    upgradeRocket.center = CGPointMake((rand()%200), -50);
    rocketlaunch = true;
}

-(int)makebigger:(int)heightnr {
  heightnr = heightnr + (1000 * rand() %5);
  if(score > heightnr) {
    [self makebigger:heightnr];
    return heightnr;
  } else {
    return heightnr;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or have a alternative way?

P.S.
The error displayed was:

> Implicit conversion of int to id is disallowed with ARC

and

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning int from a function with result type id

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

It works this way thank you very much :)

EDIT:

I got a new problem hard to solve:

this gives the error > tread 1 exc bad acces code = 2

Comment: What kind of variable does returns your method ?
If I read the declaration, I don't know, if I read after the return, it's a integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `-makebigger:(int)heightnr` to `- (int)makebigger:(int)heightnr`.

You have to specify the return type.

And you have to return something if the condition is true, too.

---

Until now I didn't even know it was possible to use no return type. But apparently it is.

Comment: Ty for this response it works but i do not want it to return when it is true so do you have an idea how to fix that without giving errors?

Comment: You do not have to do a `int a = [self makebigger:heightnr]`, you can do a simple `[self makebigger:heightnr]`, the return just will go away.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `score` is an instance variable of type `int` then you have two errors in your code: first you must specify the return type of the method otherwise `id` is assumed; and second every path must return a value and your recursive call does not do this. Correcting those gives:

```
- (int)makebigger:(int)heightnr
{
   heightnr = heightnr + (1000 * rand() %5);
   if(score > heightnr)
      return [self makebigger:heightnr];
   else
      return heightnr;
}
```

While this should work for simple value-based algorithms like this it is more usual to use iteration rather than recursion, as in:

```
- (int)makebigger:(int)heightnr
{
   while (score > heightnr)
      heightnr = heightnr + (1000 * rand() %5);

   return heightnr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess that your "score" variable is an NSNumber. The compiler is complaining because you are trying to compare an NSNumber (object) to an int.

Try this:

```
 if([score intValue] > heightnr)
```